# Can PHP detect if its run from a cron job or from the command line?

Tags: php, cron

I'm looking for way to PHP to detect if a script was run from a manual invocation on a shell (me logging in and running it), or if it was run from the crontab entry.

I have various maintenance type scripts written in php that i have set to run in my crontab. Occasionally, and I need to run them manually ahead of schedule or if something failed/broken, i need to run them a couple times.

The problem with this is that I also have some external notifications set into the tasks (posting to twitter, sending an email, etc) that I DONT want to happen everytime I run the script manually.

I'm using php5 (if it matters), its a fairly standard linux server environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding as a linked question: [Detect if a PHP script is being run interactively or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327367/detect-if-a-php-script-is-being-run-interactively-or-not/11327451)

Comment: @Leigh: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Instead of detecting when the script is run from the crontab, it's probably easier to detect when you're running it manually.

There are a lot of environment variables (in the $_ENV array) that are set when you run a script from the command line. What these are will vary depending on your sever setup and how you log in. In my environment, the following environment variables are set when running a script manually that aren't present when running from cron:

- TERM
- SSH_CLIENT
- SSH_TTY
- SSH_CONNECTION

There are others too. So for example if you always use SSH to access the box, then the following line would detect if the script is running from cron:

`$cron = !isset($_ENV['SSH_CLIENT']);`

Comment: after looking into it, this seem like the best method. between _ENV + _SERVER, i'm pretty sure i can confidently detect who/where/who is running it, and act accordingly. the CRON=running line in crontab will help too.

Comment: It seems that the default php.ini has changed over time to NOT populate the $_ENV global by default. A safe way is to use getenv('SSH_CLIENT') - see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty

Answer (score 55):

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {   
   if (isset($_SERVER['TERM'])) {   
      echo "The script was run from a manual invocation on a shell";   
   } else {   
      echo "The script was run from the crontab entry";   
   }   
} else { 
   echo "The script was run from a webserver, or something else";   
}
```

Comment: Best answer out here! I simply defined it into one of my constants: `define( 'PHP_SAPI', ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ) ? ( isset( $_SERVER['TERM'] ) ? 1 : 2 ) : 0 );`

Comment: This is definitely the best.  Answers all possible questions.  (Personally, I came here wondering about web vs. cron, so this is great!)

Comment: I'm not sure if something has changed in the last few years, but on my system (CentOS 6.6, PHP 5.4.38, running Litespeed), `php_sapi_name()` returns `cgi-fcgi` when run via cron.  In other words, if your system is like mine, you may want to swap out the first line of this answer's code with: `if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || php_sapi_name() == 'cgi-fcgi') {`.

Comment: windows  doesn't have `$_SERVER['term']`

Answer (score 33):

You can setup an extra parameter, or add a line in your crontab, perhaps:

```
CRON=running
```

And then you can check your environment variables for "CRON". Also, try checking the $SHELL variable, I'm not sure if/what cron sets it to.

Comment: i never knew you could put other commands/variable lines in the crontab like that. i only ever learned the syntax for the timed commands. this plus the php $_ENV and $_SERVER, will help what i'm trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: "man 5 crontab" for all the gritty details. But yes, you can set environment variables. Normally this is used to set PATH or perhaps SHELL, but you can set whatever you like.

Comment: Just wanted to note that `variables_order` must include 'E' in php.ini in order for the `$_ENV` array to be populated

Comment: @andrewtweber: You should still be able to use `getenv()`, unless you're blocked by safe mode.

Comment: This is a clever trick - I just used it successfully, thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Here's what I use to discover where the script is executed from. Look at the php_sapi_name function for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

```
$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if(substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) == 'cli' || empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    echo "shell";
} else {
    echo "webserver";
}
```

**EDIT:**
If `php_sapi_name()` does not include **cli** (could be *cli* or *cli_server*) then we check if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is empty. When called from the command line, this should be empty.

Comment: From the comments: Note, that the php-cgi binary can be called from the command line, from a shell script or as a cron job as well! If so, the php_sapi_name() will always return the same value (i.e. "cgi-fcgi") instead of "cli" which you could expect.

Comment: @pierdevara I did not know that! I'll edit my post accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 20):

I think that the most universal solution is to add an environment variable to the cron command, and look for it on the code. It will work on every system.

If the command executed by the cron is, for example:

```
"/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/myuser/index.php"
```

Change it to

```
"CRON_MODE=1 /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/myuser/index.php"
```

Then you can check it on the code:

```
if (!getenv('CRON_MODE'))
    print "Sorry, only CRON can access this script";
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 17):

The right approach is to use the posix_isatty() function on e.g. the stdout file descriptor, like so:

```
if (posix_isatty(STDOUT))
    /* do interactive terminal stuff here */
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, though running this on my system (and in a TTY), i get a warning: `PHP Warning:  posix_isatty(): cannot seek on a pipe in /root/test.php on line 3`, so I used the `@` in front of the call to silence the warning. Also please note that this method will detect calls in the command line that are piped to something else as "not a tty" - which is basically what I wanted, but YMMV.

Comment: @Guss: Late, but the reason pipes don't register as a TTY is because your STDOUT isn't a TTY if you are being piped out to something else; your STDOUT is another applications STDIN, not the TTY you are running it under. I believe the last application in the pipe will still see a TTY on their STDOUT.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and this is consistent with the behavior I expect to get. I want to see if its a TTY so I can do some screen manipulation - which I obviously can't do on a pipe :-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about PHP specifically but you could walk up the process tree until you found either init or cron.

Assuming PHP can get it's own process ID and run external commands, it should be a matter of executing `ps -ef | grep pid` where **pid** is your own process ID and extract the parent process ID (PPID) from it.

Then do the same to that PPID until you either reach cron as a parent or init as a parent.

For example, this is my process tree and you can see the ownership chain, 1 -> 6386 -> 6390 -> 6408.

```
UID     PID  PPID  C  STIME  TTY        TIME  CMD
root      1     0  0  16:21  ?      00:00:00  /sbin/init
allan  6386     1  0  19:04  ?      00:00:00  gnome-terminal --geom...
allan  6390  6386  0  19:04  pts/0  00:00:00  bash
allan  6408  6390  0  19:04  pts/0  00:00:00  ps -ef
```

The same processes run under cron would look like:

```
UID     PID  PPID  C  STIME  TTY        TIME  CMD
root      1     0  0  16:21  ?      00:00:00  /sbin/init
root   5704     1  0  16:22  ?      00:00:00  /usr/sbin/cron
allan  6390  5704  0  19:04  pts/0  00:00:00  bash
allan  6408  6390  0  19:04  pts/0  00:00:00  ps -ef
```

This "walking up the process tree" solution means you don't have to worry about introducing an artificial parameter to indicate whether you're running under cron or not - you may forget to do it in your interactive session and stuff things up.

Comment: Presumably, you'd set it up in such a way that 'no parameter' means you're running interactively, that way you couldn't forget it. Interesting solution though.

Comment: Yes, very interesting approach. Could have uses for other non-php things too.

Answer (score 6):

Creepy. Try

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
```

instead. PHP Client Binary dont send it. Term Type just works when PHP is used as module (ie apache) but when running php through CGI interface, use the example above!

Answer (score 5):

Not that I know of - probably the simplest solution is providing an extra parameter yourself to tell the script how it was invoked.

Answer (score 5):

I would look into `$_ENV` (var_dump() it) and check if you notice a difference when you run it vs. when the cronjob runs it. Aside from that I don't think there is an "official" switch that tells you what happened.

Answer (score 4):

In my environment, I found that `TERM` was set in `$_SERVER` if run from the command line, but not set if run via Apache as a web request.  I put this at the top of my script that I might run from the command line, or might access via a web browser:

```
if (isset($_SERVER{'TERM'}))
{
    class::doStuffShell();
}
else
{
    class::doStuffWeb();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out with Web Browser verses Command Line

Answer (score 3):

```
getenv('TERM')
```

Padding for SO's 30 char min.

Answer (score 2):

In the cron command, add `?source=cron` to the end of the script path. Then, in your script, check `$_GET['source']`.

EDIT: sorry, it's a shell script so can't use qs. You can, I think, pass arguments in the form `php script.php arg1 arg2` and then read them with `$argv`.

Comment: It's a shell script, not a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to test a specific environment variable that is set when the php file is invoked through the web and not set if runned by the commandline.

On my web server I'm testing if the APACHE_RUN_DIR environment variable is set like this :

```
if (isset($_ENV["APACHE_RUN_DIR"])) {
  // I'm called by a web user
}
else {
  // I'm called by crontab
}
```

To make sure it will work on your web server, you can put a dummy php file on your web server with this single statement :

```
<?php var_dump($_ENV);  ?>
```

Then 1) load it with your web browser and 2) load it from the commandline like this

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/yourpath/dummy.php
```

Compare the differences and test the appropriate variable.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['SESSIONNAME']` contains `Console` if run from the CLI. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I'd use php_sapi_name() - but that still won't differentiate between cron and interactive CLI execution.

Answer (score 1):

`posix_isatty(STDOUT) return FALSE` if the output of the cli call is redirected (pipe or file)...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
 blabla();
}
```

Comment: This one makes the most sense to me, except I would use if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) { blah(); }.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] isn't present when running both Cron- OR CLI-run scripts.  
The original poster is after a way to differentiate between Cron and CLI, not CLI and Web.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to run the cron commmand with an additional option at the command line that you wouldn't run manually.

cron would do:

```
command ext_updates=1
```

manual would do:

```
command
```

Just add an option in the script itself to have the ext_updates param to have a default value of false.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Cron Daemons always export `MAILTO` environment variable. Check if it exists and has a non-empty value - then you running from cron.

Comment: @shomeax why do you think it is not true? Not worse method than previous ones, and _usually_ MAILTO has some value (even if it is equals to USER), because the output always delivered via email.

Comment: *usually* MAILTO is set in the crontab, but it can as well be not. just stuck in the shared hosting setup which proves that. so for public domain scripts best method is to check for either term vars or use forcibly added environment variable as @agi suggested

Answer (score 0):

On my Amazon Linux server this is what worked for me:

$isCron = ( $_SERVER['HOME'] == '/' );

The home directory is set to yours if you just run it. If you use sudo to run it, the home directory is set to /root.

Answer (score 0):

`(array) $argv` will be set when the cron job runs.
The first value of the array will be the /path/to/file you used when creating the cron job.
The following values in `$argv` will be any parameters that followed the /path/to/file.

For example, if your cron job command looks like this:

`php /path/to/file.php first second third`

The value of $argv will be: `["/path/to/file.php", "first", "second", "third"]`

You can then:

`if (isset($argv) && is_array($argv) && in_array('first', $argv)) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score -4):

It's easy for me... Just `count($_SERVER['argc'])` and if you have a result higher than zero it will be running out of a server. You just need to add to your `$_SERVER['argv']` your custom variable, like `"CronJob"=true;`