# Why is my $_ENV empty?

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm running `Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0` and I did the following in my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv FOO bar
```

If I print out the `$_ENV` variable in a PHP file, I get an empty array. Why doesn't my environment variable appear there? Why is it empty in the first place?

I did find my variable though, but it appears in the `$_SERVER` variable. And for some reason it appears twice, sort of. Why is this?

```
[REDIRECT_FOO] => bar
[FOO] => bar
```

It appears I can get it using `getenv('FOO')`, so maybe I should just use that instead. But I am still a bit curious to what causes this. Is this a Windows issue? Or what is going on?

Comment: Not a Windows issue, it's the same in Linux (running PHP as a module). I'm not sure about the details, but it may be the enivronment of the webserver is not the same as that of PHP, and that's why it gets sent as a `$_SERVER` var. I'd give my vote for using `getenv()` which just searches them both case-insensitive as far as I gather.

Comment: On a side note: the CLI instance _does_ get it in `$_ENV`.

Comment: @svish Your update helped me. If you changed it to an answer I'd happily upvote it.

Comment: @svish Your solution posted in the question should really be posted as an answer below. This question has been linked several times as a duplicate close target, but the solution is out of place up in the question :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for the note. Good idea. Doing it now :)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Turns out there was two issues here:

**1. `$_ENV` is only populated if php.ini allows it**, which it doesn't seem to do by default, at least not in the default [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installation.

```
; This directive determines which super global arrays are registered when PHP
; starts up. If the register_globals directive is enabled, it also determines
; what order variables are populated into the global space. G,P,C,E & S are
; abbreviations for the following respective super globals: GET, POST, COOKIE,
; ENV and SERVER. There is a performance penalty paid for the registration of
; these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly used as the others, ENV is
; is not recommended on productions servers. You can still get access to
; the environment variables through getenv() should you need to.
; Default Value: "EGPCS"
; Development Value: "GPCS"
; Production Value: "GPCS";
; http://php.net/variables-order
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

When I set the [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) back to `EGPCS`, `$_ENV` is no longer empty.

**2. When you use `SetEnv` in your `.htaccess`, it ends up in `$_SERVER`, not in `$_ENV`**, which I gotta say is a tad confusing when it's named `SetEnv`...

```
# .htaccess
SetEnv ENV dev
SetEnv BASE /ssl/

# php
var_dump($_SERVER['ENV'], $_SERVER['BASE']);

// string 'dev' (length=3)
// string '/ssl/' (length=5)
```

**3. The `getenv` function will always work and is not affected by the PHP setting for $_ENV** Additionally it seems to do so insensitive to case, which might be useful.

```
var_dump(getenv('os'), getenv('env'));

// string 'Windows_NT' (length=10)
// string 'dev' (length=3)
```

Comment: AGGH! Thank you so much!!! You have no idea how long I've been googling around thinking there was a problem with mod_env or something. I completely forgot about variables_order! Thank you for being awesome!!!

Comment: Seems like the value should be set without quotes now.
(Error `PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '"' in php.ini`)

Comment: Thank you! Say, can you separate this out into three answers so I can upvote it three times? :D

Comment: Always use `$_SERVER`. `getenv()` is not thread-safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476600/how-can-getenv-be-thread-safe

Comment: @jlh Why does that matter? Nothing `getenv` returns should be changing anyways.

Comment: @Svish Calling `getenv()` multiple times may return different values, depending on how other threads are using `putenv()`. So yes, it matters.

Comment: Not if you're not using `putenv`, which I've never used ever.

Answer (score 13):

[`$_ENV`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) variables are imported from the environment under which PHP is running, and depending on your setup (the OS, your server, whether PHP runs as an Apache module or under FastCGI, etc.), this can vary greatly.

IIRC in a standard Apache+mod_php install on Windows, the only way to change variables in `$_ENV` is to change Windows' environment variables (see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519)). This can be significant when dealing with PHP extensions on Windows, because some of them (eg: [`php_ldap`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php)) are only configurable through environment vars on `$_ENV`.

Answer (score 3):

`REDIRECT_*` variables appear if you are using RewriteRules. On my server they also appear just so. It might have something to do with running under FastCGI. And if combined with suexec, that's most likely to clean up the complete environment var pool. There might be additional configuration necessary to get them back, `PassEnv` particularily. As to why getenv() works for you, I have no clue. But all phenomena are specific to your server and php configuration. Ask on serverfault, they should know.

Comment: Aha. I guessed the rewrite module might have something to do with it. Just can't quite imagine out why it's done. But I'm sure Apache has its reasons :p (or bugs)

Comment: In case you've lost sleep over why `getenv` worked: Just found out it apparently searches `$_ENV` *and* `$_SERVER` :p