# Laravel 4 accessing environment variables

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

I am trying to access an system variable within my Laravel 4 project. Similar to using `ENV['VARIABLE_NAME']` to access a system variable in an RoR project.

Within my Laravel code `getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')` returns an empty string. However, I can access and print this variable to the screen using `php -r "echo getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')"` at the command prompt.

`php -i` confirmed that this variable is also stored in php's `$_SERVER` superglobal. However, attempting to access `$_SERVER['VARIABLE_NAME']` from the database.php file of my project results in an `Undefined index: VARIABLE_NAME` error.

Can I not access arbitrary system variables from php for some reason (e.g., potential security issue, perhaps) ?  If this is the case, how can I expose the system variable I need to my Laravel 4 project?

If configuration matters, I'm using php5-fpm and nginx to serve up my PHP on Ubuntu 13.04 Server. PHP version is 5.5.

Comment: I tried to access `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` inside `app/config/database.php` and it worked just fine. May be you are trying to access `CLI` specific variable which may not be available for Web Request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After fighting with this for much longer than necessary, the proper approach is to use the php5-fpm `www.conf` file in the `pool.d` directory of your php5-fpm install. For me this was at `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

In `www.conf` there is a specific section of the file that lists several environment variables with the following syntax:

```
env[VARNAME] = $ENV_VAR_NAME
```

So just add your own and then you can then access these variables in your Laravel app with

```
getenv('VARNAME')
```

Works like a champ.

Comment: +1, it'll be useful for future reference, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) related problem, `nginx` passes parameters to `PHP` through `fastcgi_param` directives, so, you have to set it up, just add one you need where you set up other `params`, this is an example ([Setting up FastCGI Variables](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2010/07/12/getting-started-with-nginx-and-php-fpm/))

```
; /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Check [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551592/setting-env-fka-http-env-vars-with-nginx-php-fpm?rq=1) ([this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428872/environment-variables-and-php?rq=1)) as well. I can access any environment variable from `PHP` on `Apache`. Hope this helps but can't be more specific.

Comment: I investigated using the `fastcgi_params` to accomplish my goals for quite awhile. I kept hitting roadblocks with this approach. See my accepted answer for what I finally ended up doing. Thanks for contributing, though. Your source links were really helpful for understanding how nginx interacts with fastCGI.