# Access OpenShift environment vars with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, openshift

I'm trying to use OPENSHIFT environment variables in my Laravel 4 application, but it doesn't seem to work! I read the following question: [Laravel 4 accessing environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060426/laravel-4-accessing-environment-variables)
But in OnpenShift I don't have access to server config.

I always used

```
$path = $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] . 'uploads/thumbs/';
```

But `$_ENV` and `getEnv()` always returns me nothing.

How can I get that?

Comment: `getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR')` should work. If not, I think its not an Laravel problem.

Comment: It doesn't, but only with Laravel I got this problem, outside Laravel's folder it works properly, but I don't know, in some part the env vars are been cleaned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the Laravel 4 quickstart https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/laravel-4-on-openshift

Answer (score 0):

The PHP command is `getenv('my_var_name')`, which should work fine. See [PHP Environment Variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-environment-variables.html) in the OpenShift Developer Portal for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I need to set fallback values. then I can keep my local settings. So I do this

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') ? getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') :'127.0.0.1',
            'port'      => getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT') ? getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT') :'3306',
            'database'  => 'mydatabase',
            'username'  => 'admintest',
            'password'  => 'asd123asd',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```