# Accessing system variables through HHVM

Tags: laravel-4, php, docker, hhvm

**Problem: I want to access environment variables through HHVM that aren't typically exposed to a default php setup**

**Context:** I rely on a couple of system variables to provide dynamic configuration options to a Laravel4 project running in a Docker container. I want to connect to a mysql DB running in another docker container that exposes a random IP address on startup. This IP address is passed into the Laravel4 container using `--link` options for Docker and automatically exposed as a system variable in the Laravel-4 container.

**Previous approach:** When using php-fpm, I could expose system variables created by Docker to php using the `www.conf` file [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060426/laravel-4-accessing-environment-variables/20108669#20108669), and then just use getenv('VAR_NAME') to get the variable in my php code.

However, with HHVM, I cannot figure out how to access a "non-standard" environment variable. There seems to be no equivalent to `www.conf` that I can locate. Has anyone attempted this before? Is it possible to access system variables that are external to PHP using HHVM? Is there something specific to HHVM's configuration and I just can't find it in the docs?

**Additional Info:** I am behind Nginx here. I don't think fastcgi-param directives will work in my case, but I may just be doing it wrong. If anyone has accomplished what I'm trying to do using fastcgi-params, I'm fine with that approach also.

Comment: Ah ha! Think I found it under the [Server configuration settings here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options). Will respond if successful.

Answer (score 0):

`fastcgi_param` should work the exact same way in HHVM (assuming you are using HHVM as a fastcgi server, which you should be).