# getenv("PHP_SELF") returning false

Tags: php, environment-variables

Why would `getenv("PHP_SELF")` return `false`?

As `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is working and returning a **value**.

Comment: which environment you are using?

Comment: This should work, pls show how you are testing this.

Comment: @sunny Linux and Mac environment, both returning `false`.

Comment: @Anriëtte . i have put an answer for your problem, i hope it helps.

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", please don't do it next time

Answer (score 3):

That is because [`getenv()`](https://www.php.net/getenv) isn't equal to `$_SERVER` de-reference. That is: **not all** keys from `$_SERVER` are available for `getenv()` and **not all** keys have same names.

First important difference is that `getenv()` will search in case-insensitive manner. For example, this two calls will return same data:

```
$script = getenv('SCRIPT_NAMe');
$script = getenv('SCRIPT_NAME');
```

Second, about `PHP_SELF`: this is *not* the key that will be set by *environment*. Because this key has another name (or meaning, to be precise) in environment, it's `SCRIPT_NAME`. `getenv()` will use list of pre-defined keys which mostly are listed in [RFC 3875](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html)

So, if you want to use `getenv()` - you should use `SCRIPT_NAME` to refer to current script name. Note, that in *some* cases this environment key *may* be set (so you could do `getenv('PHP_SELF')`) - but you shouldn't rely on this in common case.

Answer (score 1):

ok. Actually, the problem is getenv() does not accepts "PHP_SELF" as an arguement.
Alternatively, you can use-

```
$ip=getenv('REQUEST_URI');

print_r($ip);
```

This will give you the desired result. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice there is [a slight difference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) between the values accessible with `getenv` (or `$_ENV` as [these are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798294/getenv-vs-env-in-php)) and `$_SERVER`.

- `$_ENV` gives direct access to the environment variables of the current process, which is something coming from the OS.
- `$_SERVER` gives access to additional execution information coming [from the webserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

How these arrays are populated is based on how your PHP is executed. There are different ways mainly apache-module and cgi. In both cases the superglobal variables might be filled very differently.

It's good practice to build on `$_SERVER` for scripts, which are running in the context of a webserver since  this normally contains more information concerning PHP then, which are actually needed. If you develop php applications, which should run on the command line, you will more likely want to use $_ENV to have more control of the environment.