# how can I access environment vars in php

Tags: php, environment-variables

I have set environment variable in `/etc/apache2/envvas`

```
export DATABASE='xyz'
export USERNAME='root'
export PASSWORD='pass'
```

`mode_env` is also enable.

I tried with

`var_dump($_ENV)` but the array contain nothing. how can i access it correctly ?

Comment: Try with getenv function of php

Comment: What's the different between $_ENV and getenv ?

Comment: They are the same but getenv will search case insensitive environment vars.

Comment: Please check this link for difference  :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798294/getenv-vs-env-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access env variables through this function:

```
getenv ( string $varname )
```

So, if for example you want the database name:

```
$db = getenv('DATABASE');
```

Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: can i access it from the shell as well ?

Answer (score 0):

getenv — Gets the value of an environment variable

**Description:-**

```
string getenv ( string $varname )
```

Gets the value of an environment variable.

See the Manual and you get full clarification .  [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

**Examples:-**

Example of getenv()

```
<?php
// Example use of getenv()
$name = getenv($_ENV);

// Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
$name = $_SERVER[$_ENV];
?>
```