# Best way to get user's IP?

Tags: php, ip

I've found two approaches to gives me user's IP:

**Approach1 :**

```
function get_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ip = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ip;
    }
```

**Aproach2 :**

```
function get_ip() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
        ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

May you please tell me which one is better? Actually I need to execute that function `get_ip()` per each page loading. Also as you see, the first approach has a lot of conditions (`if`-statements). So Can I simply use the second one?

In other word, is there advantage from *approach1* than *approach2*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getenv() vs. $\_ENV in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798294/getenv-vs-env-in-php)

Comment: @mistermartin The difference between those two approaches isn't only using `getenv()` and `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safer to use first one because you do more checks. Most of the time you can find the `ip` in `REMOTE_ADDR` or `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` if it's going throw proxy, but sometimes you can have in other variables because there is no standard for this.

Personally I usually go with second approach because it's more clean, but if you want to make sure you have the ip use the first one.

Also you don't need to use `getenv()`. You can check directly in `$_SERVER`

Check this answer also: [What is the difference between HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for)

Comment: You are right .. But actually I have a bad feeling about having a lot of conditions on the way of each page load. So I really don't know should I choose which one.

Comment: You don't have to worry about 5 extra `if` statement.

Comment: I wouldn't worry at all about performance with those conditionals.   Logging the IP is far more resource hungry.

Comment: I really shouldn't care about 5 `if` statements? I think that's a nightmare .. 5 conditions take a lot of process and I think it makes the performance weak. Thank you anyway .. upvote