# Do $_ENV and putenv essentially do the same thing? PHP

Tags: php

My question is simple, im trying to set some environment variables from data from a file, for use in other places in the app but i dont know why i should use $_ENV or why i should use putenv(). Ive read that they both store variables to an environment setting.

**Question**

Are `putenv()` and `$_ENV` the same thing in php? or are they truly different commands

Comment: Refer to a manual please http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php#98540

Comment: just try and set a vars using putenv() and print it with $_ENV and you'll see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getenv() vs. $\_ENV in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798294/getenv-vs-env-in-php)