# environmental variables loaded in the whole app with vlucas/dotenv

Tags: php, environment-variables

Sorry for the beginner's question, but i never completely understood how to load the dotenv library.
I have a project where the index page lies in the root directory but some other pages at the `/pages` directory.
The first question is if I have to call the `(new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__))->load();` line in all pages where i'll use env variables.
And the second question is how to call them from the other pages sitting in the `/pages` directory.
Last question: isn't there a way to load automatically the environmental variables in the whole app???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you completely dead-set on using dotenv or would you be willing to use `$_ENV` instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760375/reading-user-environmental-variable-in-php