# $_ENV not work by LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

For some reason, I need to connect database by this:

```
return array(
    'host'     => $_ENV['host'],
    'database' => $_ENV['dbname'],
);
```

I tried many things, for axample:

#### Export in .bashrc

1. add `export host="localhost"` in ~/.bahsrc
2. source ~/.bashrc
3. echo $host // localhost

`echo $_ENV['host'];` in php file is empty

#### Set in php.ini

1. edit php.ini
2. add `host = "loclhost"` at bottom
3. restart apache

`echo $_ENV['host'];` in php file is empty

#### Set in apache conf

1. add test.conf to conf-available
2. add `SetEnv host localhost`
3. a2enconf test.conf
4. restart apache

`echo $_ENV['host'];` in php file is empty, but `echo getenv['host'];` works, but I need to use $_ENV to get the environment variable.

Comment: Have a look at your `variables_order` directive in php.ini http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order Your issues is mentioned in the first user comment on the `$_ENV` manual page. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty

Comment: I indeed saw this, and I change all type of order and restart apache again and again still empty.

Comment: Ooops, I got it, it can only work on Windows?

Comment: It should work on platforms besides Windows. I've used it on Linux extensively. Are your environment vars set in `$_SERVER`?  Based on info in the other answer, if you use `SetEnv` in Apache, that populates `$_SERVER` rather than `$_ENV`.  Variables you set in .bashrc would only be available to Apache if Apache runs as a the same user as your user account, which isn't all that common except on some shared hosting