# How can getenv() be thread-safe?

Tags: c++

I want to use the [getenv()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) function.

Now I got a remark from somebody that if multiple threads are calling this function, this will not be thread-safe. However if I look at the [information page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) for this function, it states that:

> Concurrently calling this function is safe, provided that the environment remains unchanged.

I understand the concept of a static block of data, and the function returns a pointer to it. I understand that the contents of the block can change over time, by making multiple calls to the function, as the reference pages state.

If one thread is calling

```
getenv("myEnvVar1")
```

and another one is calling

```
getenv("myEnvVar2")
```

will the same memory block be used where the returned pointers are pointing to? How should I interpret the fact that "Concurrently calling this function is safe"?

Comment: I think it means that you're fine as long as you're not calling `setenv` or otherwise modifying the environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getenv` returns a pointer to the ACTUAL environment content - so the process has an array of strings with the environment variables in them, and you get back, not a copy, but the ACTUAL pointer to that.

Note that `char *p = getenv("foo"); ... setenv("foo", "new value"); ... use p` is also undefined, as the string `p` points at may well have changed now [and not in a well-defined way]

Comment: `getenv` need not be thread-safe; it is a read-only function and will not break your code. You just can't be sure the value you get is the most recent value, and you should not change the value returned by `getenv` (this, yes, can violate the runtime environment).

Answer (score 4):

### It's not.

The function `getenv` is part of the C Standard Library, thus it's behaviour is specified by the set of C standards.

### POSIX.1-2017 (Which defers to the ISO C Standard) states:

> - The returned string pointer might be invalidated or the string content might be overwritten by a subsequent call to `getenv()`,
>     `setenv()`, `unsetenv()`, or (if supported) `putenv()` but they shall not be
>     affected by a call to any other function in this volume of
>     POSIX.1-2017.
> - The returned string pointer might also be invalidated if the calling thread is terminated.
> - **The `getenv()` function need not be thread-safe.**

### ISO C11 (Which POSIX defers to), says:

> The set of environment names and the method for altering the
>   environment list are implementation-defined. **The `getenv` function
>   need not avoid data races with other threads of execution that modify
>   the environment list.**

You cannot be sure that `getenv` itself does not modify the environment when searching through it (I cannot think why it *would*, but doing so would *not violate the standard*). If you want to be sure that the version of `getenv` you're using is a thread-safe implementation, you must consult your implementation's documentation to confirm that it is.

Comment: Nope. You referred to the wrong rule. It should be "the string pointed to shall not be modified by the program, but may be overwritten by a subsequent call to the `getenv` function". However, C++ has [an explicit requirement of `std::getenv` disallowing this across different threads](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/support.runtime.general#2) since C++11. The implementation is still allowed to invalidate the pointer in the same thread once the result can be proved not shared by other threads by any well-defined operations (e.g. by returning pointer to per-thread copies).

Comment: @FrankHB"the string pointed to shall not be modified by the program, but may be overwritten by a subsequent call to the getenv function" Any reference?  "You referred to the wrong rule. "? Which one refers to the wrong rule?