# Converting timezone offset from timezone name string in C/C++ in a thread-safe way

Tags: c++, c, time

I'm trying to implement a function such that can convert a given timezone name string, which it does:

1. Accepts an input timezone string, for example, "Australia/Melbourne";
2. Checks host OS (assume it's a POSIX environment) timezone database;
3. Returns an integer of timezone offset in seconds (for Melbourne in DST, it's 36000).

It can be done by calling `putenv("TZ=Australia/Melbourne")` but this is [may not be thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479023/5378919).

Is there a way to do it without `putenv()` or somehow let it be thread-safe? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since compilers don't yet support all the features of the C++20 `std::chrono` library, I will write a solution that's using Howard Hinnant's `date`https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date library. C++20 is introducing [`std::chrono::zoned_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time) which you can use to achieve what you want.

```cpp
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto la = date::zoned_time{"America/Los_Angeles", current_time};
    auto sy = date::zoned_time{"Australia/Sydney", current_time};
    std::cout << date::format("%T\n", sy.get_local_time() - la.get_local_time());
}
```

The above example will give you the difference between two time zones. Furthermore, if you want to obtain the current OS's time zone you could use something that, I hope, will be supported by compilers in future - [`std::chrono::time_zone::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone/name).

Comment: This approach works OK usually, yet the local time's offset from UTC (a 3rd timezone here) changes between `la` and `sy`, the subtraction will give  an incorrect difference.

Comment: The difference will be correct for any value of `system_clock::time_point` used to construct the two `zoned_time`s.

Comment: Either of these `zoned_time` could be constructed with `"Etc/UTC"` to get the UTC offset of the other `zoned_time` at the point in time indicated by the `system_clock::time_point`.  And this preview of the C++20 chrono library is 100% thread-safe.  It _does_ _not_ manipulate globals such as `TZ` under the hood.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thank you for explaining this better than I would ever do. Btw I admire and respect your work

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, you will be able to use [`std::chrono::tzdb::locate_zone()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/tzdb/locate_zone), that will convert a given timezone name to a [`std::chrono::time_zone`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone) object that you can query to get the offset.

There is no standard C function that deals with time zones. There are POSIX.1-compliant functions, but they are indeed not thread-safe. However, depending on your operating system, you might be able to open the timezone database files and parse them manually. For example, on Linux you could open `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Melbourne` and parse it according to its specification in the [tzfile(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/tzfile) manpage.

Comment: Thanks. But later I'm going to run my code on Espressif ESP32. So parsing the tz file maybe not an option. I'm not even sure if there's an API for loading the file...

Comment: The tz files are very simple, and the ESP32 is quite powerful, it should not be any problem at all for it to parse timezone files quickly. I think the question is rather whether you will have a timezone database on your ESP32 to begin with. If it's not there, you will have to add your own timezone database.

Comment: Thanks. There is a "TZ file" probably embedded somewhere, since POSIX APIs like `tzset()` does work on ESP32. But how to directly access and parse it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OP's thread concerns, another consideration:

"timezone offset from timezone name string" is not sufficient in general as the offset differs depending on data/time throughout the year.

Even if no annual daylight adjustments occur in the select zone, the offset can vary due to the history of the zone.

`long offset(tz_name)` is not enough, `long offset(tz_name, time_t t)` is needed.

Comment: This answer combined with your comment under @NutCracker 's answer indicates that you understand the problem, but overlooked that NutCracker's answer does not have the flaw you claim it does.  It uses `current_time` in the computation of UTC offsets.  And more generally, could use any value of `system_clock::time_point` in that computation.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I guess we will have to disagree as I still assert NutCracker answer fails when the offset of local time changes between `la` and `sy`.

Comment: Can you come up with a concrete example?  For example NutCracker's program currently indicates a difference of 19h.  If you change `current_time` to `sys_days{March/9/2020}`, the difference is 18h, and if you change `current_time` to `sys_days{April/5/2020}`, the difference is 17h.  What are the correct answers?  Or what are the correct answers for a time of your choosing?

Comment: @HowardHinnant The result of `sy.get_local_time()` and `la.get_local_time()` represents time as if they are the local time of their retrospective timezones "America/Los_Angeles" and "Australia/Sydney".  So far no problems.  The subtraction of the two local times though is being done “as if” those local times were of a common timezone – the current local timezone.  If that local timezone is continuous between those two local times, voilà, we has the sought after difference of Sydney and LA. as per your approach ….

Comment: … If that local time zone is discontinuous (says moves an hour due to a timezone changing its UTC offset and is not related to Sydney, LA) between those two local times, the difference is an incorrect result.

Comment: You failed to provide an example.  Please find me one `system_clock::time_point` input that provides an incorrect output difference between these two time_zones.  Just one, that's all I'm asking.  I don't think it exists, unless the error is in a given version of the IANA tz database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207040/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-howard-hinnant).