# Setting environment variable in Apache + PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache

I have some problems setting a environment variable in the php-fpm pool config file.

When I set `env[SOMENAME] = somevalue` in my `/etc/php5/fpm/pool/www.conf` file php can not get the value with `$_SERVER['SOMENAME']`. Are there some config settings I have to set in apache/php to get the value from that environment variable?

Comment: I think you are pulling the cart before the horse. The title of your question is about setting environment variables in Apache and seeing the effect in PHP-FPM. But your actual question appears to be setting environment variables _exclusively_ in php-fpm. Which is it? I'm going to answer the title, because this is what google finds

Answer (score 2):

Merge Fiete's answer with Kufner's and you get the correct one.

Somewhere in Apache, you want to set an environment variable somehow:

```
SetEnv SOME_VAR "a value"
```

or with Rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E:SOME_VAR="a value"]
```

Your PHP script (according to `phpinfo()`) will have this variable for you in the `$_SERVER` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your environment variables in `/etc/apache2/envvars`.
Only add the following line in the config file and restart your apache.

```
export SOMENAME=somevalue
```

after that you can access it via `$_SERVER['SOMENAME']` in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

In Apache configuration, you can use [SetEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) directive. And for PHP FPM, you have it right.

But environment variables are not available in `$_SERVER`, they are in [`$_ENV`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) variable. So you should see your `somevalue` in `$_ENV['SOMENAME']`.

Comment: This is just wrong. `$_SERVER` is the primary place to read environment variables. Yes, it is very poorly named. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty

Comment: No, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php. But if you run PHP as module in Apache, the env variables are emulated and it may be a bit different. If you run PHP as CGI, FPM, or CLI, then you get `$_ENV`. The `$_SERVER` contains much more data than only the env variables so you cannot be sure from where the values arrived.

Comment: Yes, `$_SERVER` contains additional variables, not just the environment. But the environment is always in there, which is unfortunately not true for `$_ENV`, depending on the PHP configuration.