# Travis.ci Environment Variables not reading in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, environment-variables, travis-ci

Can someone help me understand why my environment variables aren't being read inside of my phpunit test from travis.ci?

So I'm attempting to write some automatic testing using travis for a php/javascript app I'm working on. However when I wrote a test to check for environment variables reading into phpunit from travis, they fail. That means (as far as I can tell) that either the environment variables aren't able to be read by phpunit, or they aren't being passed through to the travis test properly.

**.travis.yml**

```
language: php
php:
  - '7.0'
  - '7.1'

before_install:
  - echo "extension=ldap.so" >>php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.:\s||"``

install:
  - cd test
  - npm install
  - cd ..

script:
  - echo $API_BASE_URL
  - phpunit test/build_tests.php

notifications:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: never
```

**phpunit Test File**

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class build_tests extends TestCase
{
    public function testForEnv()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['API_BASE_URL']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['DRINK_SERVER_URL']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['LOCAL_DRINK_SERVER_URL']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['RATE_LIMIT_DROPS_DROP']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['DEBUG']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['DEBUG_USER_UID']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['DEBUG_USER_CN']), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isset($_ENV['USE_LOCAL_DRINK_SERVER']), true);
    }
}

?>
```

**travis Exporting of Environment Variables**

```
$ Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export DRINK_SERVER_URL=https://drink.csh.rit.edu:8080
$ export LOCAL_DRINK_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:3000
$ export RATE_LIMIT_DROPS_DROP=3
$ export DEBUG=true
$ export DEBUG_USER_UID=[secure]
$ export DEBUG_USER_CN=[secure]
$ export USE_LOCAL_DRINK_SERVER=true
$ export API_BASE_URL='api/index.php?request='
```

**phpunit Result**

```
PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. 

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 260 ms, Memory: 6.00MB 

There was 1 failure:

1) build_tests::testForEnv

Failed asserting that true matches expected false. 

/home/travis/build/devinmatte/WebDrink-2.0/test/build_tests.php:9

FAILURES!

Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Can someone help me understand why my environment variables aren't being read inside of my phpunit test? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does `getenv()` work instead of `$_EVV` by chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `getenv` function call instead. In travis enviroment the $_ENV variables are not available