# Get All ENV variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, environment-variables

Laravel has a .env file that contains various variables. Is there a way to get all the variables in one line of PHP code? I don't want to write

```
echo env('APP_DEBUG')
echo env('APP_URL')
etc...
```

I have tried

```
env("*")
env("*")
```

but none works.

Comment: Do you want all values from the `.env` file or all environment variables? And why would you want this?

Comment: I don't think there's an in-built mechanism for this. You may write your own code to read the file though.

Comment: @Jerodev because we have a lot of stuff in there aside from the default Laravel ENV variables. we will restrict displaying the password or secret variables.

Comment: @linuxartisan that was my first hunch but .env file is outside the public folder in laravel.

Comment: You can read any file on your server with PHP that the web server user has access to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```php
$_ENV; // gives all env variables.
```

To get a single env variable:

```php
$_ENV['VARIABLE'];
```

Comment: Wait this isn't for .env variables for Laravel, this is for PHP isn't it? OP was asking about retrieving variables from the .env file.

Comment: Nope @amir, laravel will load the . env file so you can access its variables on $_ENV you can try that on your local to see if thats working ( it is working btw )

Comment: Does depend on the PHP ini setup what var is loading the Laravel .envs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty

Answer (score 8):

The only safe way for reading all `env()` attributes is to use `Dotenv` directly :

```
$env = Dotenv\Dotenv::createArrayBacked(base_path())->load()
```

This method is usable on every environment : cli, dispatched jobs, without proper web server and even if php.ini is ignoring env.

Comment: For older versions (in 5.8 at least): `$env = \Dotenv\Dotenv::create(base_path())->load();`

Comment: Note that because this method circumvents Laravel's own implementation, there is no guarantee that the `'FOO'` key in this output will match `env('FOO')`. For example, if the configuration is cached via `php artisan config:cache`, calls to the `env()` helper may return values that differ from those output via this command. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:-

```
php artisan tinker

$_ENV
```