# Using $_ENV array in GitHub Actions

Tags: php, environment-variables, github-actions

While using GitHub actions I get an undefined index error in `$_ENV('ENV')` but when I use `getenv('ENV')` I actually get the variable I'm looking for. How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my $\_ENV empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty)

Answer (score 1):

> If your $_ENV array is mysteriously empty, but you still see the
>   variables when calling getenv() or in your phpinfo(), check your
>   http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order ini
>   setting to ensure it includes "E" in the string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php#98113