# Laravel application $_ENV array is empty after running composer update

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, laradock

After updating my laravel application with `composer update` my .env file is not loaded into scripts anymore. When I `var_dump($_ENV)` I get an empty array.

I use docker - and precisely laradock - to host my application. I only boot `docker-compose up nginx mariadb` so I only have the following containers running: nginx, php-fpm, workspace, mariadb and docker-in-docker.

When I ssh into the container `docker-composer exec workspace /bin/bash` and `cat .env` in the `/var/www` directory, I see that the .env file with all variables is available inside the container. But still, the `$_ENV` array is empty.

Solutions provided [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty) did not work form me. As laradock is not part of my composer definition nothing changed about the server setup and there is no `.htaccess` file that might mess things up as nginx is doing the job.

Any ideas where to start debugging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my $\_ENV empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have been looking into that one before. But as laradock is not part of my composer definitions nothing changed about the server setup. `variables_order` is as it was and also I don't have an .htaccess that might mess up due to nginx doing the work