# PHP can't access environment variables, error occurs when i quickly reload the page

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm using WAMP, with PHP 7.3. To get the environment variables, i'm using the [PHP dotenv package](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). I am getting the following error when I reload the page too often / too fast.

[image: error]

The databaseConnector.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Common;

class DatabaseConnector{
    public static function getConnection(){

        $drive = $_ENV['DB_DRIVE'];
        $host = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
        $port = $_ENV['DB_PORT'];
        $db = $_ENV['DB_NAME'];
        $user = $_ENV['DB_USER'];
        $pass = $_ENV['DB_PASS'];

        try{
            return new \PDO($drive.':host='.$host.'; port='.$port.'; dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);
        } catch (\PDOException $e){
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I access the page normally, this error does not occur. What might be causing this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The code does not show where you define the environment variables

Comment: Maybe interesting? [Why is my $_ENV empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace App\Common;

class DatabaseConnector{
    public static function getConnection(){
        GLOBAL $_ENV; // add this line
        $drive = $_ENV['DB_DRIVE'];
        $host = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
        $port = $_ENV['DB_PORT'];
        $db = $_ENV['DB_NAME'];
        $user = $_ENV['DB_USER'];
        $pass = $_ENV['DB_PASS'];

        try{
            return new \PDO($drive.':host='.$host.'; port='.$port.'; dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);
        } catch (\PDOException $e){
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why? How does your change explain that the code works sometimes, and fails at other times?

Comment: Also, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php, `$_ENV` is available everywhere without using `global`