# How to enable or disable multiple "echo statements" in bash ecript

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash script where i have echo before every command showing what is happening.

But i need to disbale echo when setting as cron job and then enable again if do some testing.

i find it very hard to go to each line and then add/remove comment

is there anything which i can include at top something like

```
enable echo or disable echo
```

so that i don't have to waste time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The absolute easiest would be to insert the following line after the hashbang line:

```
echo() { :; }
```

When you want to re-enable, either delete the line or comment it out:

```
#echo() { :; }
```

If you're not using `echo` but `printf`, same strategy, i.e.:

```
printf() { :; }
```

If you *absolutely* need to *actually* echo/printf something, prepend the `builtin` statement, e.g.:

```
builtin echo "This 'echo' will not be suppressed."
```

This means that you can do a conditional output, e.g.:

```
echo () {
  [[ "$SOME_KIND_OF_FLAG" ]] && builtin echo $@
}
```

Set the `SOME_KIND_OF_FLAG` variable to something non-null, and the overridden `echo` function will behave like normal `echo`.

---

***EDIT:*** another alternative would be to use `echo` for *instrumenting* (debugging), and `printf` for the outputs (e.g., for piping purposes). That way, no need for any `FLAG`. Just disable/enable the `echo() { :; }` line according to whether you want to instrument or not, respectively.

---

### Enable/Disable via CLI Parameter

Put these lines right after the hashbang line:

```
if [[ debug == "$1" ]]; then
  INSTRUMENTING=yes  # any non-null will do
  shift
fi
echo () {
  [[ "$INSTRUMENTING" ]] && builtin echo $@
}
```

Now, invoking the script like this: `script.sh debug` will turn on instrumenting. And because there's the `shift` command, you can still feed parameters. E.g.:

- Without instrumenting: `script.sh param1 param2`
- With instrumenting: `script.sh debug param1 param2`

The above *can* be simplified to:

```
if [[ debug != "$1" ]]; then
  echo () { :; }
  shift
fi
```

if you *need* the instrumenting flag (e.g. to record the output of a command to a temp file *only* if debugging), use an `else`-block:

```
if [[ debug != "$1" ]]; then
  echo () { :; }
  shift
else
    INSTRUMENTING=yes
fi
```

**REMEMBER:** in non-debug mode, *all* `echo` commands are disabled; you have to either use `builtin echo` or `printf`. I recommend the latter.

Comment: i tried that but gave some error , i had the statement like `echo "Backing up ...."$FOLDER/$DATE` . did that line has any problem

Comment: @Mahakaal I just tested, and I got no error. But then again, you should put `$FOLDER/$DATE` *inside* the quotes, i.e. : `"Backing up ... $FOLDER/$DATE"`

Comment: i tried adding that line at below hashbang , and then i tested without any echo statement , i still get error it says `Unexpected end of file`

Comment: @Mahakaal ... omigosh, I just realized: It should be `:;` instead of just `:`. I've been testing the 'conditional output' one. I'll fix my answer. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: wow that worked perfectly , that was the answer i was looking for , all others were sort of hacks but this was prefect. also is it possible that i can pass something on commandline and then it displays echo othwise not like  `/bin/sh  abc.sh yes` and then it displays echos

Comment: @Mahakaal sorry, just saw your question. Yes, use the version with the 'FLAG'. Test $1 for your signal, and if $1 matches your signal, set the FLAG variable to something not null.

Comment: @Mahakaal I've further edited my answer to show you how it's done.

Answer (score 12):

Several things:

#### Don't use echo at all

Instead use `set -xv` to set debug mode which will echo each and every command. You can set `PS4` to the desired prompt: for example `PS4='$LINENO: '` will print out the line number on each line. In BASH, I believe it's the same. Then, you don't have to clean up your script. To shut off, use `set +xv`.

Example:

```
foo=7
bar=7
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -xv   #Begin debugging
if [ $foo = $bar ]
then
    echo "foo certainly does equal bar"
fi

set +xv   #Debugging is off

if [ $bar = $foo ]
then
    echo "And bar also equals foo"
fi
```

Results:

```
$ myprog.sh
if [ $foo = $bar ]
then
    echo "foo certainly does equal bar"
fi

5: [ 7 = 7 ]
7: echo 'foo certainly does equal bar'
foo certainly does equal bar
set +xv   #Debugging is off

And bar also equals foo
```

#### Use a function

Define a function instead of using echo:

Example:

```bsh
function myecho {
    if [ ! -z "$DEBUG" ]
    then
        echo "$*"
    fi
}
```

```bsh
DEBUG="TRUE"
my echo "Will print out this line"
unset DEBUG
myecho "But won't print out this line"
```

#### Use the *nop* command

The colon (:) is the nop command in BASH. It doesn't do anything. Use an environment variable and define it as either *echo* or *:*. When set to a colon, nothing happens. When set to `echo`, the line prints.

Example:

```bsh
echo=":"
$echo "This line won't print"
echo="echo"
$echo "But this line will."
```

Comment: This works with sh too, for those curious

Answer (score 2):

Building on Matthew's answer, how about something like this:

```
myEcho = "/bin/true"
if [ ! "$CRON" ]: then
    myEcho = "/bin/echo"
fi
```

and then use `$myEcho` instead of `echo` in your script?

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably use an alias, then it isn't even a variable (and you could alias echo itself).

Comment: That's not valid bash syntax. You need to have no spaces around the `=` signs (if you do, it will be interpreted as executing the command `myEcho` with `=` as its first argument), and use a semicolon or newline instead of the colon between the `if` and `then`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I miss the below solution to use a variable (e.g. debug) at the start of the bash script.

Once you set the debug=true, any conditional-if will enable or disable multiple “echo statements” in bash script.

```
 typeset debug=false # set to true if need to debug
...
 if [ $debug == "true" ]; then
     echo
     echo "Filter"
     read
 fi
...
 if [ $debug == "true" ]; then
     echo
     echo "to run awk"
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one better. If you setup your crontab as detailed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190759/can-php-detect-if-its-run-from-a-cron-job-or-from-the-command-line/190796#190796), you can then check if you are running in cron and only print if you are not. This way you don't need to modify your script at all between different runs.

You should then be able to use something like this (probably doesn't quite work, I'm not proficient in `bash`):

```
if [ ! "$CRON" ]; then
  echo "Blah blah"
fi
```

Comment: True, but if he has lots of echo statements that could be kinda annoying to wrap them all in a guard `if` like that.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: It's a once off job, then it's done. Beats changing your script every time you are running it, since he's already commenting every single echo anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try `set -v` at the top to echo each command.  To stop echoing change it to `set +v`.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't post a code block in a comment, so I'll post this as an answer.

If you're a perfectionist (like I am) and don't want the last `set +x` line to be printed... and instead print `Success` or `FAIL`, this works:

```
(
  set -e # Stop at first error
  set -x # Print commands
  set -v # Print shell input lines as they are read

  git pull

  // ...other commands...

) && echo Success || echo FAIL
```

It will create a sub process, though, which may be an overkill solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it in cron, why not just dump the output? Change your crontab entry so that it has `> /dev/null` at the end of the command, and all output will be ignored.