# PHP and Cron job

Tags: php, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the canonical way to determine commandline vs. http execution of a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173851/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-determine-commandline-vs-http-execution-of-a-php-s)

Is there some "conditional" tags in php for cronjob? What i want to make:

```
if(cron_job_executing_this_php_file)
{
do something
}
elseif($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "blah.bl.ah.bl")
{
do something
}
```

Can i do something like this?

Comment: why not just make a separate php file for your cron job?

Comment: you might be able to if your crontab is able to send a $_GET variable  0  3  *  *  * sudo /usr/local/bin/myfile.php?cron=true

Comment: Seems to be an exact duplicate of [Can PHP detect if its run from a cron job or from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190759/can-php-detect-if-its-run-from-a-cron-job-or-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [php_sapi_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php). It should return a different value from the command line (including, but not limited to, cron) than from say CGI or mod_php.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add an arg to you PHP call inside you crontab:

```
0 1 0 0 0 php myscript.php from_cron
```

And then test for it in the script:

```
   foreach($argv as $value)
   {
      echo "$value\n";
   }
```

It's safer than to rely on the $SERVER super global.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

If you put in something as follows:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
    // Do non-shell stuff here
} else {
   // Do shell stuff here
}
```

Comment: I think you should reverse your comments, do non-shell stuff if REQUEST_METHOD is set.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument into the php script from cron.

Something like

`01 04 1 1 1 /path/to/my/script.php "fromcron"`

Then your `script.php` can ask:

`if($argv[1]=="fromcron")`.

You may have some index errors, so don't ask for $argv[1] unless you know it's going to have an element at index [1].