# CRON PHP access restrcitions

Tags: php, security, cron, restriction

I have a PHP script that is run by a cron job once nightly. I would like to restrict users from accessing this script. Cron should be the only thing that should be able to run this.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP detect if its run from a cron job or from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190759/can-php-detect-if-its-run-from-a-cron-job-or-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you! Found the answer in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achive that i suggset that you add a second argument to your cron instruction look like this :

```
/the/path/toyour/cronjob/file/cron.php -- password
```

Then test the argument number 3 ($argv[2]) if it is valid or not

```
$pass = (isset($argv[2]))?$argv[2]:"";
if ($pass != 'your password')
{
die('Password is incorrect!');
}
```

Then by this method you prevent any user from accessing the script directly because arguments cannot be set from other than internal jobs

Hope this is helpfull and any help needed i am here :)